# Make a dropdown menu to choose an object in array?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to using javascript and d3. I have a csv file of colleges and have created an array of each of these college object along with the attributes that belong to each college. I wan to create a drop down menu for the user to be able to select the college they would like to view the statistics of. I know how to make a bar graph given the statistic but do not know how to give the user the option of a drop down menu to select the college object and then how to pass the data from the selected object a graph. Could someone help me out. I will  file and the code I have so far.

Here is a snippet of the csv file I am working with

```
Name,Predominant Degree,Highest Degree,Control,Region,Locale,Admission Rate,ACT Median,SAT Average,Undergrad Population,% White,% Black,% Hispanic,% Asian,% American Indian,% Pacific Islander,% Biracial,% Nonresident Aliens,% Part-time Undergrads,Average Cost,Expenditure Per Student,Average Faculty Salary,% Full-time Faculty,% Undergrads with Pell Grant,Completion Rate 150% time,Retention Rate (First Time Students),% Undergrads 25+ y.o.,3 Year Default Rate,Median Debt,Median Debt on Graduation,Median Debt on Withdrawal,% Federal Loans,% Pell Grant Recipients,Average Age of Entry,Average Family Income,Median Family Income,Poverty Rate,Number of Unemployed 8 years after entry,Number of Employed 8 years after entry,Mean Earnings 8 years After Entry,Median Earnings 8 years After Entry
Abilene Christian University,3,4,Private,Southwest,Mid-size City,0.4894,24,1087,3647,0.7069,0.076,0.1206,0.0099,0.0036,0.0005,0.0373,0.0417,0.0398,39811,8737,5508,0.9204,0.2347,0.5637,0.7941,0.0381,7.5,20698.5,26237.5,9500,0.970000029,0.439999998,20.22999954,86392,75873.5,7.800000191,130,1327,39800,37200
Adams State University,3,4,Public,Rocky Mountains,Remote Town,0.526,20,939,2227,0.5123,0.0768,0.3026,0.0112,0.0153,0.0063,0.04,0,0.1612,17759,7996,5986,0.5088,0.5029,0.227,0.5592,0.2106,9.3,11000,0,11000,0.829999983,0.730000019,24.12999916,45711.23,34243,11.84000015,99,752,33600,30700
Adelphi University,3,4,Private,Mid-Atlantic,Large Suburb,0.6814,22,1098,5000,0.5296,0.1062,0.1336,0.0756,0.0016,0.002,0.022,0.0396,0.0952,41559,12142,11315,0.3203,0.2951,0.6251,0.8112,0.1562,3.7,21325,25000,13000,0.949999988,0.449999988,23.12999916,74831.68,54115,7.46999979,152,1524,52200,49400
Adrian College,3,3,Private,Great Lakes,Distant Town,0.5628,22,1007,1616,0.7605,0.1002,0.0217,0.0056,0.0037,0.0006,0.0384,0.0006,0.021,40199,7091,7453,0.4767,0.4368,0.5445,0.5811,0.023,7.7,14250,27000,7655,0.99000001,0.479999989,19.62999916,77959.35,71008.5,5.710000038,34,393,35000,33800
```

and here is the code I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: All vehicles</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> 
        <style type="text/css">
            h1 {
                font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .area {
                stroke: none;
            }
            .area:hover {
                fill: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Colleges</h1>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Width and height
            var width = 1000;
            var height = 1000;
            var padding = 20;

            var dataset, xScale, yScale, xAxis, yAxis, area;  //Empty, for now
            //For converting strings to Dates
            var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");
            //For converting Dates to strings
            var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%b %Y");
            //Set up stack method
            var stack = d3.stack()
                          .order(d3.stackOrderDescending);  // <-- Flipped stacking order

            //Setting up the scales 
            //Load in data
            d3.request("colleges.csv")
                .mimeType("text/csv")
                .get(function(response) {
                    //
                    // DATA PARSING
                    //
                    //Parse each row of the CSV into an array of string values
                    var rows = d3.csvParseRows(response.responseText);
                    //console.log(rows);

                    //Make dataset an empty array, so we can start adding values
                    dataset = [];
                    schoolvsSATvsACT =[]

                    //Loop once for each row of the CSV, starting at row 3,
                    //since rows 0-2 contain only vehicle info, not sales values.
                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

                        //console.log(rows[i][0]);

                        //Create a new object
                        dataset[i - 1] = {
                            // school: rows[i][0]  //Make a new School object for each school
                            school: rows[i][0]
                        };
                        //Loop once for each vehicle in this row (i.e., for this date)
                        //for (var j = 1; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
                            var school = rows[i][0];
                            var predominantDegree = rows[i][1];  //'Make' from 1st row in CSV
                            var highestDegree = rows[i][2];  //'Model' from 2nd row in CSV
                            var control = rows[i][3];  //'Make' + 'Model' will serve as our key
                            var region = rows[i][4];  //'Type' from 3rd row in CSV
                            var local = rows[i][5];  //Sales value for this vehicle and month
                            var act = parseInt(rows[i][7]);
                            var sat = parseInt(rows[i][8]);
                            var white = parseFloat(rows[i][10]);
                            var black = parseFloat(rows[i][11]);
                            var hispanic = parseFloat(rows[i][12]);
                            var asian = parseFloat(rows[i][13]);

                            // //If sales value exists…
                            // if (sales) {
                            //  sales = parseInt(sales);  //Convert from string to int
                            // } else {  //Otherwise…
                            //  sales = 0;  //Set to zero
                            // }
                            //Append a new object with data for this vehicle and month
                            dataset[i - 1] = {
                                "School" : school,
                                "PredominantDegree": predominantDegree,
                                "HighestDegree": highestDegree,
                                "Control": control,
                                "Region": region,
                                "Local": local,
                                "ACT" : act,
                                "SAT" : sat,
                                "White" : white,
                                "Black" : black,
                                "Hispanic" : hispanic,
                                "Asian" : asian
                            };  
                        //}
                    }
                    console.log(dataset);
                    //Log out the final state of dataset
                    // console.log(dataset);
                    // console.log(rows[0].school);

                    xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){ 
                        return d.ACT; })]).range([0,height]);
                    yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){ 
                        return d.SAT; })]).range([0,width]);
                    var maxValue = d3.max(dataset,function(d){
                        return d.SAT;
                    });

                    console.log(parseInt(maxValue));

                    var svg = d3.select("body")
                                .append("svg")
                                .attr("width",width)
                                .attr("height",height);

                            svg.selectAll("circle")
                                .data(dataset)
                                .enter()
                                .append("circle")
                                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                                        return xScale(d.ACT);
                                })
                                .attr("cy", function(d) {                               
                                        return yScale(d.SAT);
                                })
                                .attr("r", 1);


                    // svg.selectAll("text")
                    // .data(dataset)
                    // .enter()
                    // .append("text")
                    // .text(function(d){
                    //  return d.ACT + "," + d.SAT;
                    // })
                    // .attr("x", function(d){
                    //  return xScale(d.ACT);
                    // })
                    // .attr("y", function(d){
                    //  return yScale(d.SAT);
                    // }).attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    // .attr("font-size", "11px")
                    // .attr("fill","red");

                    // var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
        //          var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale);

                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        //console.log(rows[i][0]);

                        //Create a new object
                        schoolvsSATvsACT[i - 1] = {
                            school: rows[i][0]  //Make a new Date object for each year + month
                        };
                        //Loop once for each vehicle in this row (i.e., for this date)
                        //for (var j = 1; j < rows[i].length; j++) {

                            var ACT = rows[i][7];
                            var SAT = rows[i][8];  //'Make' from 1st row in CSV


                            // //If sales value exists…
                            // if (sales) {
                            //  sales = parseInt(sales);  //Convert from string to int
                            // } else {  //Otherwise…
                            //  sales = 0;  //Set to zero
                            // }
                            //Append a new object with data for this vehicle and month
                            // dataset[i - 1][school] = {
                            //  "predominant Degree": predominantDegree,
                            //  "Highest Degree": highestDegree,
                            //  "Control": control,
                            //  "Region": region,
                            //  "Local": local
                            // };   
                        //}
                    }
                            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a drop down with D3, you want something like this -

```
var dropdown = d3.select("#your-dropdown-location")
                    .insert("select", "svg")
                    .on("change", dropdownChange);

dropdown.selectAll("option")
                    .data(dataset)
                  .enter().append("option")
                    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.school; });


function dropdownChange() {

var newSchool = d3.select(this).property('value');
//Update bar graph...

}
```

May require small tweak to the setting of the value to accommodate the format of your data set.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This did the job!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. If it did answer your question, you should "accept" the answer so others viewing later with a similar concern can know how to solve it.